# Use server object model check if SPListItem field is a SPUser or SPGroup

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, development

I am making a TimerJob that duplicates ListItems from one SiteCollection to another. In order to do this I need to copy the Users and Groups over to the other site. I am having trouble identifying whether the SPFieldType is a user or group so that I can apply the correct logic.

Since a `Person Picker` field can either be a `SPUser` or a `SPGroup` I'm having difficulty. I have a hook in the logic to see if it is of `SPFieldType.User` like this:

```
if (sourceField.Type == SPFieldType.User)
{
    //need to see if it is a SPUser or SPGroup in here
    //if (SPUser) then use EnsureUser to create the user if it does not exist
    //if (SPGroup) then use some other logic to create the group if it does not exist
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the field value as [SPFieldUserValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfielduservalue%28v=office.14%29.aspx) and check if the `User` property is null.

```
SPFieldUserValue userFieldValue = new SPFieldUserValue(yourSPListItem.Web, yourSPListItem[sourceField.Id].ToString());
if (userFieldValue.User == null) // userFieldValue is SPGroup
{
    // do group processing
}
else // userFieldValue is SPUser
{
    // do user processing
}
```

If your field can contain multiple values, and there could be a mix of users and groups, you can use the same idea with [SPFieldUserValueCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfielduservaluecollection%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

```
SPFieldUserValueCollection userFieldValueColl = new SPFieldUserValueCollection(yourSPListItem.Web, yourSPListItem[sourceField.Id].ToString());
foreach (SPFieldUserValue userFieldValue in userFieldValueColl)
{
    if (userFieldValue.User == null) // userFieldValue is SPGroup
    {
        // do group processing
    }
    else // userFieldValue is SPUser
    {
        // do user processing
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the field value as [SPPrincipal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spprincipal.aspx) and then check is it a user or group.

```
if (principal.GetType() == typeof(SPUser))
{
    SPUser user = principal as SPUser;
    //your code for SPUser
}
else if (principal.GetType() == typeof(SPGroup))
{
    SPGroup group = web.SiteGroups.GetByID(principal.ID)
    //your code for SPGroup
}
```

Comment: I tried assigning the `listItem[field]` as `SPPrincipal` like so: `SPPrincipal principal = version[sourceField.Title] as SPPrincipal;` but it returns null. the variable version is a SPListItemVersion btw. Any advice on this?

Comment: You can't get SPPrincipal directly by just casting the object returned from item[field]. Maybe its quicker and with fewer steps to user SPFieldUserValue as Dylan proposed. If userFieldValue.User == null then it's a group and get it with SPGroup group = web.SiteGroups.GetByID(userFieldValue.LookupId). Otherwise it's a user and just get it with userFieldValue.User.